# ID Large, broad flat bone found in Gulf of Mexico

Tags: species-identification, zoology, herpetology, bone

[image]`[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y19Xf.jpg)

Is this a tooth? A rib? Or a fish?

I found this in about 4’ of water in the Gulf of Mexico/Galveston.
It is slightly curved and the side edges have numerous pointy parts. On one side at the bottom it has what looks like the root or something that attached to something else. It is sitting on my thigh. I am a 5’9” male. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Excellent picture, bizarre and intriguing object, I'll be following this one closely. Welcome to the site.

Comment: Well it seems like there was a similar bone found in Missouri and identified here. Turtle. This great site. Very detailed explanation of that question. I am satisfied that what I found was part of the back of a sea turtle.